# Login screen keeps resetting?

Tags: login, errors, upgrade

This problem occurred after I upgraded Wordpress and the screen went blank. Prior to upgrading, I deactivated one of the plugins on the site cuz it was preventing me from accessing the plugins page and users page.  But anyways, I Was finally able to get the login screen to come up but it keeps resetting everytime I try logging in.  No error or anything.  The form just resets itself.  Any ideas?

Comment: Which plugin was causing the problem for upgradation ?

Comment: It was a menu editor plugin.

Comment: Do you have Varnish enabled ?

Comment: No, I don't think I remember it being installed on the site.

Comment: Is the problem on your local server or a live site ? If it is on live site then is it a wp specific one ? if yes then check with your hose if they have Varnish enabled for caching and if they do then make sure the login page is excluded from caching .

Comment: My question is...why can I login via Chrome and not on Firefox even after I delete cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear all the cookies and try reloading the page and logging again.

Hope that will work

Comment: I tried logging in using a different browser.  Was able to login on Chrome.  Not sure why it doesn't work on Firefox.  So still gotta fix the problem on Firefox.  The problem still occurs even if I clear cookies.